# How do you include external libraries when you cross-compile c programs using mingw?

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, ncurses, mingw-w64

I am building a simple command line game in C using the [ncurses library](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) on a Linux machine but I want to be able to run the compiled code on a Windows computer. To do this, I am using the [MinGW-w64 cross compiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) tool in Linux and compiling it to run in a 64 bit Windows environment. However, when I try to compile using this command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o game.exe barebones.c -lncurses
```

I get this error:

```
barebones.c:2:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <ncurses.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed ncurses on my Ubuntu machine and can create and run the same simple program to run on Linux. I have been able to cross-compile and run simple programs that only use the default libraries. I think I must be listing the ncurses library incorrectly in the compliation command or that I am failing to understand other posts that show that this doesn't work.

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: How did you specify the location of ncurses, which you built with the cross-compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Debian provides no cross-compiling packages for ncurses.  (Ubuntu provides no additions or improvements to ncurses in any way, simply reusing packages from Debian).  If you want to cross-compile ncurses, you'll have to build ncurses in cross-compiling form.

For development purposes, ncurses packages can be built using the scripts under the (sources) [*packages*](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/tree/master/package) directory, e.g., after downloading the [current source](https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/ncurses.tar.gz):

```
tar xf ncurses-whatever.tgz
cd ncurses-whatever
cp -var packages/debian-mingw64 ./debian
dpkg-buildpackage
```

That's a starting point.  You'd have to do something about the email in the `debian/control` file to appease `dpkg-buildpackage` (tutorials are off-topic).